# Store property of button which launched action

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

On `form1` I want to store the name of the button which called this form so I can execute some code depending upon the button click

```
button bt1=new button();
button bt2=new button();

private void b1_click(object sender, eventargs e)
{
    form1 f1=new form1();
    f1.show();
}

private void b2_click(object sender, eventargs e)
{
    form1 f1=new form1();
    f1.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this, I suggest one of the following ways

Using the forms constructor:

ie

```
form1 f1 = new form1("MyButtonName");
```

and then in the constructor of the form

```
public form1(string buttonName)
{
    this.ButtonName = buttonName;
}
```

or setting the property manually

```
form1 f1 = new form1();
f1.ButtonName = "MyButtonName";
```

I prefer using the former, as it forces you to specify the button that creates the new form.

Note: You can change the property name to whatever you like.

Comment: Thank You Johan and Lajos Arpad

Comment: @user1058384 all fixed now?

Answer (score 0):

Add a property or a member in form1 called CallerName.

Set it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want provide new form only one parameter, i agree that good solution of problem is create constructor with one parameter as johan shows.

If you want make more changes on form before you showing it, you can create property on form, which while is set, setting form properties, or methods.
Its good while you need modify behavior of one form which is used at more than one places in code.

For example form modified by properties with default constructor:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public string HeaderText
    {
        get {return this.Text;}
        set {this.Text = value;}
    }

    private MyLayoutEnum _LayoutStyle;
    public MyLayoutEnum LayoutStyle
    {
        get
        {
            return this._LayoutStyle;
        }
        set
        {
            this._LayoutStyle = value;
            switch (value)
            {
                case MyLayoutEnum.Basic:
                    {
                        //do work
                        break;
                    }
                case MyLayoutEnum.Advanced:
                    {
                        //do work
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        //unsupported case - for example
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

public enum MyLayoutEnum : int
{
    None = 0,
    Basic = 1,
    Advanced = 2
}
```